# Decorators in Python Class for DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class

I have the following dataframe class.
I want to add two checks in each of the probability functions that I will create.

First, check that the value exists in a Pandas Series (see probability zero function) and then check that the column exists in the DataFrame.

How can I create decorators for all of my probability functions? I plan to create several of them including conditional probabilities etc.

```
from functools import wraps

class Probabilities():
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.dataframe)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.dataframe}"
    
    def __getitem__(self, column):
        return self.dataframe[column]
    
    def probability_zero(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            probability = func(*args, **kwargs)
            if probability == 0:
                return print("Value Not In Column!")
            else:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    
    @probability_zero
    def _absolute_probability(self, column, value):
        try:
            bool_result = (self.dataframe[column] == value)
            return bool_result.mean()
        except KeyError:
            print("Column not in table.")

    def absolute_probability(self, column, value):
        val = self._absolute_probability(column, value)
        if val is not None:
            formatted_val = f"""Probability of value: "{value}" in column: "{column}" is {val*100:.1f}%"""
            return formatted_val


p_df = Probabilities(bank_df)

p_df.absolute_probability("jobb", "management")
```

Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could create a decorator that checks for the required conditions and then apply it to whatever function you want.The code is like this:

```
def probability_check(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        _self,column,value = args
        if column not in _self.dataframe:
            return print("Column not in table.")
        probability = func(*args)
        if probability == 0:
            return print("Value Not In Column!")
        else:
            return func(*args)
    return wrapper

class Probabilities():
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.dataframe)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.dataframe}"
    
    def __getitem__(self, column):
        return self.dataframe[column]
    
    @probability_check
    def _absolute_probability(self, column, value):
        bool_result = (self.dataframe[column] == value)
        return bool_result.mean()

    @probability_check
    def conditional_probabilities(self, column, value):
        pass

    def absolute_probability(self, column, value):
        val = self._absolute_probability(column, value)
        if val is not None:
            formatted_val = f"""Probability of value: "{value}" in column: "{column}" is {val*100:.1f}%"""
            return formatted_val
```